# Q-Tree How to add checkbox for all nodes

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have dynamic data which is fetched from server. I'm using Vue.js and Q-Tree by Quasar framework.
When the data is static the checkbox (`tick-strategy = 'leaf'`) works.
But when data is fetched from server I cannot understand why the checkbox is not shown, and one more interesting thing - the checkbox will be visible when I expand level until leaf

the code is a standard:

In `mount` life circle I have promise which fetch the data.

```
data () {
return {
allData: []
}
```

}

```
    mount () {
       Promise.all(....)
       .then (data => { this.allData = data;})        
    }
```

So and now in template I have:

```
<q-tree 
  :nodes="allData"
node-key="id"
@lazy-load...
:tick-strategy="leaf"
:ticked.sync="ticked"

...
```

So, now the nodes are shown without checkbox, and appears until expand to leaf.

Comment: Can you post an example of how your data coming from the server looks. You will probably have to iterate through that data so you can restructure it to match the node model structure before sending to the q-tree component: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/tree#Nodes-model-structure